# Observing frequency of waveform in LTspice

Tags: frequency, ltspice

I'm using Ltspice for circuit simulation. I stimulate the circuit using run command in the menu stimulate. But I didn't find how to measure(simply in hertz) frequency from there. So how can I observe the frequency of a waveform from LTspice?

Comment: If the signal is periodic, maybe you can try right click on the plot and do FFT and see all about the frequency content of your signal. The peak of the FFT will indicate the signal's fundamental frequency. You might need to window it.

Comment: By now, you've received, including the suggestion here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49589214/observing-frequency-of-waveform-in-ltspice, 4 hints about using FFT as a means to do it, yet you selected the answer that uses the cursors, even if you, yourself, make a commment about it not being "automated" (which I doubt any simulator does without a FFT, or some `.meas`-like commands). Of course, you could automate it yourself by using some A-devices and an integrator (optional, S&H), and that will be automated...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Double click on the part of the circuit you want to measure and a waveform window should pop up (when the simulation is running) and your waveform you want to measure will show. Either adjust the runtime of the simulation or zoom in on the waveform so you can actually see the entire waveform cycles. Then click on part of the cycle and drag your mouse the the exact same point to the next cycle - the bottom of the waveform window will show the frequency of the distance between these two points.
[image]

Click on image and you will see what I mean.

Comment: So I've to measure frequency like we use the manual cursor for DSO. No way to way to auto-track the frequency.

Comment: This "mouse cursor" method is error-prone. FFT analysis should be used.

Answer (score 6):

As Vicente commented, mouse-based methods are error-prone. That being said, if you don't need an exact measure, and for completeness, here is another mouse based method:

Enable two graph "cursors" by clicking the name of the waveform you want to measure (see below, circled in red). The first click will create one cursor, another click will create another cursor. Note that if you don't move the first one, the second will be created on top of the first (not an issue).

[image: ltspice Waveform graph]

Now hover your mouse-cursor over the uh, waveform-cursor. Your mouse-cursor should become a yellow number (1 or 2, see below). You can then click and drag the cursor to move it.

[image: ltspice waveform cursor]

At this point, you can line up your two waveform-cursors across one complete cycle. The frequency, along with other information, will be shown in the small cursor window (see below).

[image: ltspice waveform cursor frequency measurement]

Also note that sidA30's method will zoom after un-clicking, which can be annoying. To avoid zooming, you can right-click before letting go of the left-click. This cancels the selection and thus doesn't zoom.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: right-click the waveform, go to "View"->"FFT", then select the waveform from menu and an appropriate number of samples.

Page 31 of [this manual](http://www.ieca-inc.com/images/Spice-Simulation_Using_LTspice_Part_1.pdf) goes into more details.